# Good references for representations of GL(2)

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, representation-theory, algebraic-number-theory, automorphic-forms

I am studying the book 'Automorphic forms and representations' by Daniel Bump. Currently, I'm reading chapter $4$.

There are many good references for the first section, so I understood almost every theorems in this section.

Currently, I'm stuck in section $4.5$, i.e., 'The principal series representations'. I have found a few notes that talk about these representations, but their approach is different.

Can someone suggest some notes that follow Bump's book and fill out the gaps? I am asking this since I have to give some lectures on this chapter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Gelbart’s book (*Automorphic forms on adele groups*) springs to mind, but I haven’t read it so I can’t guarantee that it fits your needs.

Comment: @Aphelli Thanks for the comment. I have checked Gelbart's book and it does not help much.

Comment: The point of Bump's book was to fill in the gaps of things like Gelbart's book.

Comment: Look at Chapter 6 (if memory serves) of Goldfeld-Hundley.